# Odd responses using Google Maps Geocode Lookup (API key)

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I've been working with website that uses geocode lookups via Google. I've been testing this for awhile now.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Pennsylvania+Ave+NW,+Washington,+DC&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I've got that key locked to particular servers.  All of a sudden I'm seeing geocode lookup errors.  The response back from Google is:

```
{
    error_message: "Browser API keys cannot have referer restrictions when used with this API.",
    results: [ ],
    status: "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

When I try a simple request without the API key at all it seems to work fine. Here you can try this yourself.  Copy and paste the next line in your browser's URL and return.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Pennsylvania+Ave+NW,+Washington,+DC
```

Now, I probably shouldn't look a gift horse in the mouth, but the whole thing seems odd.  If I remove my API keys today, will my websites, that rely on an address to Lat/Lng conversion, all fail tomorrow?

Is anybody else experiencing odd failures with Google Maps and GeoCode lookups?  Is anyone aware of a systemic content or policy change from the Google mapping / GeoCoding team??

Edit, update:
So this defect lasted about 40 minutes, from around 9:10PM PST until a bit before 10PM PST.  It seems to be fixed now.

Response to comment:  Hmmm.  I've been looking at the API keys as:

> Server keys: Create and use a Server key if your application runs on a
>   server. Do not use this key outside of your server code. For example,
>   do not embed it in a web page. To prevent quota theft, restrict your
>   key so that requests are only allowed from your servers' source IP
>   addresses.
>
> Browser keys: Create and use a Browser key if your application runs on
>   a client, such as a web browser. To prevent your key from being used
>   on unauthorized sites, only allow referrals from domains you
>   administer.

I'm definitely doing this complete lookup from user directly to Google without a server in the middle.  No way can I safely use a Server key there.  So I've read your input, and it definitely says Server key for geocoding.  But, that really implies that no one should ever allow a browser / client interaction to process a geocode lookup. Frankly I just assumed the writeup was out of date and a bit inaccurate.

While you may be right, the whole thing just looks odd.  I would have thought that if Geocode required a lookup from a server (only) and never from a web application via the browser (ever) that there would have been some direct comment as to that effect.

Oh, and the browser keys, with server fencing, seem to be working again.  Again, I'm just saying the whole thing is odd.  I'm treating this as a temporary hiccup up at the Google geocode servers.

And yes, I can certainly introduce an API server for a round trip Ajax call to do the lookup safely with a server key, but what's the point? Is there a benefit that I'm just not seeing? I guess I could add elements like a nonce to protect my round trip geocode intermediate lookup server from somebody else using it, etc....  But at this point, I'm just confused.

Update #2:  16 Jun 2016
Again, this whole thing is not clear.  I filed a [feature request to the Google GeoCode team](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9954) asking for a clarification update to the documentation to address the use of Browser API keys for geocode lookups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation for the Geocoding Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key) states:

> Standard API users: If you're using the API under the standard plan, you must use a **server key** (a type of API key) set up in a project of your choice.

The error message indicates you are using a **browser key**.

Comment: I hear what you are saying.  I'm thinking that sounds just way odd on Google's part.  Why would they possibly do it that way?  (Why geocode from servers only, why not from web browser?)  See my edit above.

Comment: On client side you have Maps JavaScript API and its geocoder service. So from browser it's recommended to use geocoder service https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Comment: @xomena  I'm not sure I understand your point. The link you provided includes `If instead you wish to geocode static, known addresses, see the Geocoding web service documentation.`  I'm not using a static known address.  A user comes to the web page where I ask them to type in their street address.  From there I geocode the street address to a lat/lng and then pull up a google map.  This is all done in a few lines of code in JavaScript in the browser.  No way I'm using a server API key there, that is just wrong.  I hear what geocodezip is saying, but I doubt that is intended.

Comment: See update #2 to my original question above, ref: feature request to Google GeoCoder asking for clarification to the API documentation.

Comment: So the official word from the Google team is `Usage of 'Keys for browser applications' or 'Browser keys’ with the Google Maps API Web Services was deprecated on August 30, 2015. Developers should instead use ‘Server keys’ with these services. Any requests to Google Maps Web Services APIs using such keys will fail.` per [this link.](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=9954)